# How to get error message of validator from TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I want to get error message programmatically to display somewhere else. Example error show *Text is too short*, I can get it by using `_formKey.currentState...` . How to get there?

```dart
Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: TextFormField(
    validator: (value) {
      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please enter some text';
      }
      if (value.length < 5 ) {
        return 'Text is too short';
      }
      return null;
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: If you do not have any questions left, I would appreciate if you could accept and upvote my answer for future reference.

Comment: I did, thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Add a variable and reassign the value from your validator:**

```
String? errorMessage;

void saveForm() {
final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
// If isValid == true > process the save logic, else show error dialog e.g.
if (!isValid) {
// show dialog
return;
}
  _formKey.currentState!.save();
 // Use your saved data
 }
```

**Use the validator return value to perform your save logic conditionally:**

```
Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: TextFormField(
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
            errorMessage = 'Please enter some text';
            return false;
          }
          if (value.length < 5 ) {
            errorMessage = 'Text is too short';
            return false;
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),
    )
```

**Inside your widget tree:**

```
final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();

isValid ? SizedBox() : Text(errorMessage)
```

Comment: Thanks for your question. Could you have any way to get message from ```_formKey```?

Comment: That is not the purpose of a formkey. Please take a look at [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation).